# How do I count unique grapheme clusters in a string in Rust?

Tags: unicode, rust

For example, for

```
let n = count_unique_grapheme_clusters("    ");
println!("{}", n);
```

the expected output is (space and three flags: `" "`, `""`, `""`, `""`):

```
4
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use the `graphemes` method from [unicode-segmentation crate](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) to iterate over the grapheme clusters and save them in a `HashSet<&str>` to filter out the duplicates. Then we get the `.len()` of the container.

```
extern crate unicode_segmentation; // 1.2.1

use std::collections::HashSet;

use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

fn count_unique_grapheme_clusters(s: &str) -> usize {
    let is_extended = true;
    s.graphemes(is_extended).collect::<HashSet<_>>().len()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(count_unique_grapheme_clusters(""), 0);
    assert_eq!(count_unique_grapheme_clusters("a"), 1);
    assert_eq!(count_unique_grapheme_clusters(""), 1);
    assert_eq!(count_unique_grapheme_clusters("é"), 2);
    assert_eq!(count_unique_grapheme_clusters(""), 3);
}
```

[Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5255adc9b5f3681c484e4f86189d9eee&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you can tick the `Answer your own question` checkbox at the bottom of the ask question page, so that you can write your question and your answer at once.