# How to iterate over Unicode grapheme clusters in Rust?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, rust

I am learning Rust and I just have been surprised by the fact that Rust only is able to distinguish UTF-8 byte sequences, but not actual grapheme clusters (i.e. a diacritic is considered as a distinct "char").

So for example, Rust can turn input text to a vector like this (with the help of `"नमस्ते".chars()`):

```
['न', 'म', 'स', '्', 'त', 'े'] // 4 and 6 are diacritics and shouldn't be distinct items
```

But how do I get a vector like this?

```
["न", "म", "स्", "ते"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count unique grapheme clusters in a string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51818497/how-do-i-count-unique-grapheme-clusters-in-a-string-in-rust)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may want to use [the `unicode-segmentation` crate](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation):

```rust
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation; // 1.5.0

fn main() {
    for g in "नमस्ते".graphemes(true) {
        println!("- {}", g);
    }
}
```

([**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a69064b707bbfe1a834a381014867ca), note: the playground editor can't properly handle the string, so the cursor position is wrong in this one line)

This prints:

```
- न
- म
- स्
- ते
```

The `true` as argument means that we want to iterate over the extended grapheme clusters. See [`graphemes` documentation](https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes) for more information.

---

Segmentation into Unicode grapheme clusters was supported by the standard library at some point, but unfortunately it was [deprecated](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24428) and then [removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27684) due to the size of the required Unicode tables. Instead, the de-facto solution is to use the crate. But yes, I think it's really unfortunate that the "default standard library segmentation" uses codepoints which semantically do not make a lot of sense (i.e. counting them or splitting them up generally doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Nurbol Alpysbayev Let me know if I correctly copied the string and if the result is correct. I unfortunately do not understand this script and cannot really compare it to your expected result.

Comment: Ahh, so using the crate is the de-facto standard of doing that? Frankly I've searched some crate without success. Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I added some explanation regarding it being the de-facto solution.