# How do I convert a single character String to a char?

Tags: rust

This issue seems trivial but I can't find an answer. Assuming that `letter` is a single character string, how could I convert letter to a char?

```
let mut letter = String::new();

io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut letter)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

Comment: If you happen to be already using [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.exactly_one): `letter.chars().exactly_one().expect("not exactly one")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use [`chars` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars). This return an iterator over the `char`s of a string slice.

```
let letter_as_char: char = letter.chars().next().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", letter_as_char);
```

But it is [important to remember that](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#examples-52)

> `char` represents a Unicode Scalar Value, and might not match your idea
> of what a ‘character’ is. Iteration over grapheme clusters may be what
> you actually want. For example, Consider the String `H`
>
> ```
> let y = "H";
>
> let mut chars = y.chars();
>
> assert_eq!(Some('H'), chars.next());   
> assert_eq!(None, chars.next());
> ```
>
> Now consider `"y̆"`
>
> ```
> let y = "y̆";
>
> let mut chars = y.chars();
>
> assert_eq!(Some('y'), chars.next()); // not 'y̆'
> assert_eq!(Some('\u{0306}'), chars.next());
>
> assert_eq!(None, chars.next());
> ```

See also:

- [How to iterate over Unicode grapheme clusters in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770462/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-grapheme-clusters-in-rust)