# Get value of nth char in string in rust

Tags: string, rust

How do I get the value of a character at position *n* in a string?
For example, if I had the string "Hello, world!", how would I get the value of the first character?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simple as `s.chars().nth(n)`.

However, beware that like said in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars):

> It’s important to remember that [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html) represents a Unicode Scalar Value, and might not match your idea of what a ‘character’ is. Iteration over grapheme clusters may be what you actually want. This functionality is not provided by Rust’s standard library, check crates.io instead.

See [How to iterate over Unicode grapheme clusters in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770462/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-grapheme-clusters-in-rust).

For the first character specifically, you can use `s.chars().next()`.

If your string is ASCII-only, you can use [`as_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes): `s.as_bytes()[n]`. But I would not recommend that, as this is not future-proof (although this is faster, O(1) vs O(n)).